# Acordeon dinámico

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, accordion

En la imagen se muestra el resultado que obtengo actualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito agrupar por categorías los elementos de un acordeón.

El código que tengo actualmente me genera un `accordion-item` por cada uno.
Este es el código:

```php
    <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="faqlist">
              <?php
              $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipos_apuestas WHERE codigo_apuesta = ?");
$sth->bindParam(1, $codigo_apuesta);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {

foreach ($sth as $row ) { ?>

     <div class="accordion-item">
                <h3 class="accordion-header">
                  <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#faq-content-1_<?=$row["id"]; ?>">
                    <i class="far fa-star fa-lg"></i>
                   <?= $row["categoria"] ?>
                  </button>
                </h3>
                <div id="faq-content-1_<?=$row["id"]; ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#faqlist">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <div class="contenedor">
                      <a class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-cuota="<?= $row["cuota"]; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);"><?= $row["descripcion"]; ?></a>
                      
                    </div><br>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div><!-- # Faq item-->

<?php }

}
 
              ?>

            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
```

Cualquier ayuda será altamente agradecida.

Comment: Hola Samael, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Sinceramente no entiendo que es lo que necesitas. Quizas si nos dieras un ejemplo de lo que se imprime actualmente y como quisieras que sea podríamos ayudarte. Por lo que creo entender, parece que cada `tipos_apuestas` pertenece a una categoria y ¿que se repite? por eso quisieras agruparlas, cierto?. PD te recomiendo realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primer medalla.

Comment: En el query directamente puedes agrupar por categoría `WHERE codigo_apuesta = ? GROUP BY categoria`

Comment: Si pongo group by solo genera un accordion-item hasta aquí bien, pero solo muestra el primer elemento dentro del accordion-body y son varios

Comment: @Marcos Correcto eso es lo que quiero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías conseguir lo que necesitas realizando lo siguiente:

- Primero hacemos una consulta para obtener las categorias utilizando `GROUP BY`

  ```
  SELECT categoria 
  FROM tipos_apuestas 
  WHERE codigo_apuesta = ?
  GROUP BY categoria
  ```
- Luego, por cada categoria, hacemos una consulta para obtener los tipos de apuesta.

  ```
  SELECT id, cuota, descripcion
  FROM tipos_apuestas 
  WHERE codigo_apuesta = ?
     AND categoria = ?
  ```

#### Ejemplo:

```php
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="faqlist">
  <?php

  // Buscamos solo las categorias
  $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT categoria 
    FROM tipos_apuestas 
    WHERE codigo_apuesta = ?
    GROUP BY categoria");
  $sth->bindParam(1, $codigo_apuesta);
  $sth->execute();

  if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {

    $categories = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($categories as $idx => $cat) { ?>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h3 class="accordion-header">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#faq-content-1_<?= $idx; ?>">
            <i class="far fa-star fa-lg"></i>
            <?= $cat["categoria"] ?>
          </button>
        </h3>
        <div id="faq-content-1_<?= $idx; ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#faqlist">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <div class="contenedor">
              <?php

              // Buscamos los tipos de la categoria
              $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT id, cuota, descripcion 
                FROM tipos_apuestas 
                WHERE codigo_apuesta = ?
                  AND categoria = ?
                ORDER BY descripcion ASC");
              $sth->bindParam(1, $codigo_apuesta);
              $sth->bindParam(2, $cat["categoria"]);
              $sth->execute();

              $tipos = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              foreach ($tipos as $row) { ?>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-cuota="<?= $row["cuota"]; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);"><?= $row["descripcion"]; ?></a>
              <?php
              } ?>
            </div><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- # Faq item-->
  <?php
    }
  } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias caballero,justo lo que ocupaba,te lo agradezco mucho,bendiciones!!! @Marcos

Comment: Saludos @Marcos, talvés puedas ayudarme, tengo un código para enviar mensajes con el api de whatsapp,tengo el siguiente código: